# Got merge conflict shows 2 branches

Tags: git, branch, conflict

Why does git always shows 2 branches - Parent 1 and Parent 2 in logs when there is a merge conflict and you push the changes post resolving those conflicts after doing a git pull?

How does it work exactly in case of merge conflict?

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 1):

A merge commit *is* a commit with two<sup>1</sup> parents, regardless of whether there were conflicts to resolve.  One point of confusion in Git is that not all `git merge` *actions* result in merge *commits*, though.

In any case, when you make a merge commit, that leaves a trail for Git to show later, during `git log`, or to see later, for a subsequent merge operation, for instance.  This tells Git that, at and beyond the point of the merge, the result is what the person who *did* the merge, intended.  If there were conflicts—or sometimes, even if not—the merge result is *not* exactly the same as simply "taking both sets of changes".

When you run `git merge theirbranch`, Git:

1. identifies your current commit (HEAD)
2. identifies the tip commit of the branch *`theirbranch`*
3. finds the *merge base* of these two commits.

This merge-base commit is the point at which your branch and their branch were last "together", i.e., were last in sync due to either not having diverged, or having been merged.  Now that Git knows which it is, and assuming some other conditions are met,<sup>2</sup> Git goes on to:

4. diff the merge base against your HEAD commit: this is "what you did";
5. diff the merge base against their tip commit: this is "what they did"; and
6. *combine* both sets of changes, applied to the merge base, to make a new commit.

You get a merge conflict when you and they made *different* changes to the same part(s) of the same file(s).  In this case, Git will put *both* changes into the file in the work-tree, and stop before making the new commit.  It's then your job to fix the work-tree version of the file, `git add` the result, and run `git commit` to finish the merge.  As you have seen, the conflicted parts—the stuff Git could not merge on its own—are surrounded by conflict markers.  There may be additional changes that Git *did* resolve on its own, in the same file, depending on what you did and what they did.

If you made the *same* change to some part of some file, Git takes just one copy of that change!  For instance, if you both deleted a line with a misspelled word, and put in a line with the word spelled correctly, Git does not try to delete the original line twice, nor put in *two* copies of the fixed line.

If all goes well—if there are no merge conflicts—`git merge` will `git add` all the files and run `git commit` for you.  You can prevent the last step by adding `--no-commit` to the command.  In this case, Git stops even if there are no merge conflicts, which lets you test and, if necessary, alter the merge result before committing the merge.  This is another way to make a merge different from just "combine the changes".

If you have started a merge but have not finished it (due to `--no-commit` and/or merge conflicts), you can *abort* the merge entirely with `git merge --abort`.  This removes all the partial resolutions and goes back to the state you had before you started the merge.

Again, though, in all cases of real merges, the final commit, if you make one, has *two* parent commits.  The first parent is the commit that was `HEAD` when you started.  The second parent is the tip commit of *`theirbranch`*.  The new commit gets added to your current branch as usual.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, a merge is any commit with two *or more* parents.  Three-or-more parent merge commits are called *octopus merges*.  They don't do anything you can't do with ordinary merges, so they are mainly for showing off your Git-fu. :-)  (More seriously, they're for tying together several branches at once, to show that the goal was to tie up all those branches.)

<sup>2</sup>If the merge base *is* the HEAD commit, there is nothing to merge.  If the merge base is the other tip commit, the merge can be done as a "fast forward".  If there is *no* merge base, newer versions of Git tell you that the histories are not related (older versions merge against the empty tree, which is at least a little odd, but is still allowed if you use `--allow-unrelated-histories`).

Meanwhile, `git merge` also has the `--squash` option, which tells it to run the merge *machinery*—the two diffs and the combining—but to make the new commit have only *one* parent, instead of two.  The resulting commit (which you must make manually as well) is not a *merge commit* and a later Git operation will think that the histories of the two branches were *not* combined.  This will make Git do a lot more work, and over time the branches may become very difficult to merge, without real merge commits.

Answer (score 0):

If git finds conflicts during the merge, it will list all files that have conflicts after the error message. You can also check on which files have merge conflicts by doing a 'git status'.

To find the conflict with in a file ,
<<<<<<<: This indicates the start of the lines that had a merge conflict

Find some useful commands below .

```
git diff
```

A command that helps find differences between states of a repository/files. Useful in predicting and preventing merge conflicts.

```
git diff origin/master <fileName>
```

Find the differences between the current index (HEAD) of fileName and what is in the central repository (origin/msater)

Changes coming from origin/master are marked with +, while changes that are in your local repository (HEAD) are marked with -.

```
git status
```

It is the command that provides an overview of all files that have been modified and are in conflict at the time of the merge.